# How to define a custom action to execute when the cancel button (at uninstallation) is pressed in WiX Toolset?

Tags: wix

I have found that the cancel button should be defined like this:

```
<Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="Cancel">
    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelButton"/>
</Control>
```

And a publish event is defined to the custom action, which could be defined like:

```
<CustomAction Id="CancelButton" Execute="immediate" ExeCommand='Program.exe"   Return="ignore"/>
```

An error shows up:  **Unresolved reference to symbol 'Dialog:CancelButton'**

A Dialog element in WiX cannot have a custom action as child, so where should be defined that custom action?

Two links with related information:

- [How to cancel an uninstallation using CancelDlg](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/How-to-cancel-an-installation-using-CancelDlg-td704211.html)
- [Custom Action as event](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Custom-action-as-Event-td689561.html)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved this by using a custom action with a particular field, "OnExit". So you only need to create the custom action and link it with:

```
<Custom Action="MyAction" OnExit="cancel" />
```